# Magento 2 - how to set theme as parent theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I created a new theme. I want to use the Luma theme as the base theme.

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>My Template</title>     <!-- your theme's name -->
   <parent>Magento/luma</parent>   <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
</theme>
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you enable your new theme from backend???

Comment: Yes, I activated it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute these commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:clear

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Edit:** Im not sure why, but now many ressources are pending and can't get loaded.

[image]

**Edit 2:** I noticed that they are just getting loaded extremly slow for unknown reasons, but after a while all get loaded successfully.

Comment: is it working fine for you ?

Comment: Yes, now it works.

Comment: ok great :) thanks

Comment: But it always loads now, many ressources cant get loaded... they are pending